# Javascript array - split

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a text file in which I have data on every line. It looks like this:

```
number0;text0
number1;text1
number2;text2
```

..and so on

So I loaded that text file into a variable via xmlhttprequest and then I converted it into an array using split by "\n" so now the result of lineArray[0] is number0;text0.. And now what I need is to split that array again so I could use number0 and text0 separately.

My idea being that I want to get the text0 by searching number0 for example lineArray[i][1] gives me texti..

Any ideas how to proceed now?

Thanks

Comment: Just split all the arrays by semicolon too ..?

Comment: You already split the text by "\n". Why don't you try with ";" ?

Comment: I tried that but it gave me an error the method cant be used or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing I'm late, still making a contribution.

As everyone else said, split it again.

```js
let text = "number0;text0\nnumber1;text1\nnumber2;text2"
let data = text.split('\n');
var objects = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  let key = data[i].split(';')[0]; // Left hand value [Key]
  let value = data[i].split(';')[1]; // Right hand value [Value]
  
  // Add key and value to object
  objects[key] = value;
}

// Access by property
console.log(objects);
```

---

Using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let text = "number0;text0\nnumber1;text1\nnumber2;text2"
let data = text.split('\n');
var objects = {};

data.forEach((elem) => {

  let key = elem.split(';')[0]; // Left hand value [Key]
  let value = elem.split(';')[1]; // Right hand value [Value]
  
  objects[key] = value;
});
// Access by property
console.log(objects);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an additional split on `;` as `split(';')` so that `lineArray[0][1]`, `lineArray[1][1]` and so on gives you `text0`, `text1` and so on.

```js
var str = `number0;text0
number1;text1
number2;text2`;
var lineArray = str.split('\n').map(function(item){
   return item.split(';');
});
console.log(lineArray);
console.log(lineArray[0][1]);
console.log(lineArray[1][1]);
```

Comment: @TomášVítů glad to help

Comment: Use plain function then. Check my updated answer @TomášVítů

Comment: @TomášVítů glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Just use split again with ";", like that:

```
myVar = text.split(';');
```

like @Teemu, @Weedoze and @Alex said

Answer (score 0):

#### Convert the array into an object

Make an object out of it with another String split. To do so you can use the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to convert the array of strings into an object.

```js
const strings = ['number0;text0', 'number1;text1', 'number3;text3', 'number4;text4'] ;

const obj = strings.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  const [key, value] = curr.split(';');
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj)
```

This way you can access `text4` buy calling `obj['number4']`.

---

#### More about [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

The reduce method works by looping through `strings`

- on each step `acc` is the *accumulator*: it contains the object that is getting filled with key/value pairs.
- `cur` is the current item in the step
- `const [key, value] = curr.split(';')` will to split the string into two strings and assign each to a seperate variable: `key` and `value`. It's called  [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- then I assign the key/value pair to the *accumulator*
- the `.reduce`method will return the *accumulator* on his state on the last step of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do the trick:

```js
let a = "number0;text0\nnumber1;text1\nnumber2;text2";
let lines = a.split('\n');

let vals = [];
for(let line of lines) {
  vals.push(line.split(';'))
}
console.log(vals); // Output
```

The last four lines create an empty array and split on the ';' and append that value to the `vals` array. I assume you already have the something like the first 2 lines